# Dynamically pass a value in Gravity Forms

Tags: wordpress, forms, gravity

I have a widget on a form that maps the distance between two addresses.  And I want to take the distance (in miles) from this widget and pass it to a product field in Gravity Forms, and then perform a calculation.  How do I isolate this  value and add it to the form?

Comment: Sounds like this will take some Javascript -- Is the Gravity Form on the same page as the distance widget?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.